# Keycloak returning Account not fully setup error after migration to 18v

Tags: keycloak

I was using keycloak v6.0.1 initially and now its been migrated to keycloak v18.0.2. I have been using an additional deployment to login via totp rather than password. So for the new users its giving an error as below

```
{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Account is not fully set up"}
```

The configuration was working fine with v6.0.1. And the users were able to login with otp rather than a password. But now after migration its throwing the above error.
I have already unchecked the Update Password in Authorization > Required Actions module.

**UPDATES**

The issue is solved when am trying to set the Credential Type as TOTP rather than PASSWORD. But the issue is occurring again for the other set of users who rely on PASSWORD based login.

Please find my configirations below:
[image]

[image]

In the UI, under the Required Actions there are no entries, but in database I can see an entry under the table user_required_action

[image]